# Fixing site load times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my site takes a millennia to load even though it has barely anything in it. My assumption is that it's because there are quite a few images and JavaScript on the page.

Is there a way to test for what is causing the long load times?

Comment: Install the firefox and it's plugin firebug

Comment: You'll probably want to look at reducing down your file sizes and the number of HTTP requests. Merge and minimise your JS and CSS files and reduce the image sizes (your background image is on the large side in terms of kb).

Comment: @enve strange bounty given the OP's url is now a link farm site.

Comment: You can always place a link to the concerning website so we can give it a spin :D

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Test your page here [PageSpeed Insights - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) and you will see all suggestions for making your site faster.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.jj-triggs.com_2F&mobile=false&rule=OptimizeImages

Comment: great answer thankyou, thats such a useful tool!!! google impresses me yet again :)

Comment: Not sure it will help you an awful lot to optimize the size of the images. I'm sitting on a 100Mbit up/down connection and after a minute the site still hasn't loaded.

Comment: No, the site I suggested does not help to optimize images. But some other sites like yahoo smushit, tinypng etc. may help

Comment: @Enve Your bounty description says "the current answers do not contain enough detail". But there are many answers with a lot of helpful information. What detail are you looking for, exactly?

Answer (score 28):

Here are some basic things you can follow to increase your site speed:

1. **Post-load content**: Don't load all of your stuff like JavaScript files, images, data, at first. Make a flow of which content your user should see first and load it in that order.  This will reduce the user's perceived waiting time because they will be able to look at the loaded parts of the site while the other stuff loads.
2. **Pre load content**: Benefit from the user's idle time. Load content in the backgroud using Ajax or image-caching tricks, so the user will not notice that the page is still "working". Because files are pre-loaded into the browser's cache already, when the user loads the  next page or view, it will seem very fast because the data is already stored locally.
   (In short, the main idea behind post and pre-loaded content is to show the user what they want at first and then load other content in the background before they need to see that content. Use JavaScript or jQuery Ajax to load your content and cache them.
3. **Optimize Images**:

   1. Reduce the quality of images to a extent which the human eye cannot figure out. You can compromise a little bit of image quality for greatly decreased file sizes, and thus much greater download/load speed.
   2. Don’t use the browser to downscale images: Don’t send a huge image and let the browser scale to a significantly smaller size using CSS width and height. Manually size your image to roughly the correct size, even if you do want to use some scaling like a fully-stretched background image.
   3. Use CSS replacement for the images.
   4. Use CSS sprites: Combine your small images to one image and show the proper part using CSS.
   5. Make images cacheable.
4. **Keep CSS on top**: Keeping CSS on top make you feel page is loading faster. As CSS is applied as portion of content is loaded.
5. **Keep JavaScript at the bottom**:  JavaScript is used to manipulate DOM elements, so load the DOM element first so that the page will be rendered first, and then load your script. JavaScript also blocks parallel downloads.
6. **Minify JavaScript and CSS**: Minifying CSS and JavaScript can reduce its size up to 50 to 30 % of the original copy.
7. **Use External CSS and JavaScript**:  .css and .js files are cacheable, so use external CSS and JavaScript files.
8. **Split component across domains**: Split your component into two or three domains like `example.com` to `com1.example.com` and `com2.example.com`. This allows you to maximumize parallel downloads. Don’t keep more than two to four domains otherwise it will give you a DNS lookup penalty.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man for improving readability of my answer.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the list where you can test your webpage:

1. [PageSpeed Insights - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)
2. [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/)
3. [Webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org)
4. [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com)
5. [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)
6. [iWebTool](http://www.iwebtool.com/speed_test)
7. [APM Cloud Monitor](http://cloudmonitor.ca.com/en/checkit.php)

Also to speed up your page you can use:

1. [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
2. [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) - has free plan

---

**1. Optimize Your Images**

Know when to use the appropriate file format for your images. Changing to a different file format can dramatically decrease the file size of an image.

- **GIF** - is ideal for images with few colors like logos.
- **JPEG** - is great for images with lots of colors and details like photographs.
- **PNG** - is the choice when you need high quality transparent images.

Check out these resources to learn more about optimizing images:

- [The Comprehensive Guide to Saving Images for the Web](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/comprehensive-guide-saving-images-for-web/)
- [JPEG 101: A Crash Course Guide on JPEG](http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/jpeg-101-a-crash-course-guide-on-jpeg/)
- [Web Designer’s Guide to PNG Image Format](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/web-designers-guide-to-png-image-format/)
- [8 Excellent Tools for Optimizing Your Images](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/8-excellent-tools-for-optimizing-your-images/)

For reducing your image size I would recommend [TinyPNG](http://www.tinypng.org)

---

**2. Don’t Scale Down Images**

Avoid using a larger image than you need just because you can set the `width` and `height`attributes of `<img>` elements in HTML.

<sub>* If you need a 100x100px image and you have a 700x700px image, use an image editor like Photoshop or one of these web-based image editors to resize the image to the needed dimensions. This lowers the file size of the image, thus helping to decrease page loading times.</sub>

---

**3. Compress and Optimize Your Content**

The task of compressing your website content can have a huge impact on reducing load times. When using HTTP compression, all of your web page data is sent in a single smaller file instead of a request that is full of many different files. For more information, see this Wikipedia article on [HTTP Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

You can also optimize and compress your JavaScript and CSS files by combining them and minifying the source code.

---

**4. Put Stylesheet References at the Top**

Moving your stylesheet references to the `<head>` of your HTML document helps your pages feel like it is loading faster because doing so allows your pages to render the styles progressively. In addition, it doesn’t hurt that it’s the W3C standard.

---

**5. Put Script References at the Bottom**

Browsers can only download two components per hostname at the same time. If you add your scripts towards the top, it would block anything else below it on the initial loading of the page. This makes it feel like the page is loading slower.

To avoid this situation, place script references as far down the HTML document as possible, preferably right before the closing `<body>` tag.

---

**6. Place JavaScript and CSS in External Files**

If your JavaScript and CSS are directly in your HTML document, they are downloaded every time an HTML document is requested. This, then, doesn’t take advantage of browser caching and increases the size of the HTML document.

Always place your CSS and JavaScript in external files; it’s a best practice and makes your site easier to maintain and update.

---

**7. Minimize HTTP Requests**

When visiting a new web page, most of the page-loading time is spent downloading components of that page (e.g. images, stylesheets, and scripts).

By minimizing the number of requests a web page needs to make, it will load faster. To reduce HTTP requests for images, one thing you can do is to use [CSS sprites](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-sprites-site-speed/) to combine multiple images.

If you have multiple stylesheets and JavaScript libraries, consider combining them to reduce the number of HTTP requests.

---

**8. Cache Your Web Pages**

If you use a [content management system](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-evaluate-what-cms-to-use/) that dynamically generates your web pages, you should statically cache your web pages and database queries so that you can decrease the strain on your server as well as speed up page rendering times.

---

**9. Reduce 301 Redirects**

Every time a 301 redirect is used, it forces the browser to a new URL which increases page-loading times. If possible, avoid using 301 redirects.

Comment: Thank you, the answer contains most of the details that I need.

Comment: Also good for image compression http://picturecompressing.com/

Answer (score 8):

The other answers here do a good job of detailing performance debugging tools and tips to improve load times, so I won't repeat them.

**Your main problem is that you load absolutely everything in your site before displaying your homepage to the visitor**. This is unnecessary, and is the main contributor to the perception that your site loads slowly.

I can understand that you want to preload as much as possible, so that as the visitor browses your site, everything will seem to load instantly. However, all you're doing is moving the small load times for each section into one huge up-front load time. Where a visitor might browse only one area of your site, they are still paying for the load time of the whole site, instead of just the sections they visit.

The easiest way to implement small load times is to split each section into its own page, and then loading only what you display on that page. Resources such as Javascript and CSS usually cache pretty well, so you usually don't need to worry about their load times impacting anything other than your homepage.

Alternatively, assuming you want to keep your whole site on one page, you will need to dynamically add the various sub-sections to the page using Javascript, once everything required for your homepage has finished loading and the progress bar has been hidden. Yes, if the visitor is quick to click on a sub-section, they will see its content being loaded in, but if they're only interested in your Contact Me section, they will be able to get the information they need a lot sooner without even noticing that the other sections haven't fully loaded yet.

That, and don't use huge background images. It's okay to upscale a lower resolution image to fill the screen, and to up the JPEG compression level to decrease the file size. It's a background image and should not be a focal point - leave the high resolution images for your portfolio. :)

Comment: Agree with the points you're making except that the "main issue" is loading everything first. That's usually perfectly fine for a small portfolio site like this. If he wasn't using uncompressed JPEGs for everything the standard loading wouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome has [a console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network?hl=us) where you can view loading times of the site and all things that need to be downloaded.

Answer (score 7):

Install the FireBug plugin into FireFox, then load your site with the NET tab open in FireBug. You can see how long each resource takes to load.

It looks like there are two background images that take over 20 seconds each to load.

**Update**

The world has moved on quite a bit since I posted this. Chrome now provides an Audits tab that enables you to simulate a range of devices and network speeds etc, along with Network, Performance and Memory analysers. 
The lighthouse plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en is pretty good as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have few suggestions to improve the load time:

1. You are using three background images, while only one is shown. Either remove the other two or load them later.
2. Convert PNG images to JPEG and see if you can save on size.
3. Load standard JavaScript files from the cdn repository instead of loading them from your server. There is a good chance that file may be found in its cache.
4. Minify your JavaScript files after concatenating them, if you have not done so.

Answer (score 5):

So: Yes, you really need to fix your site. People won't wait to load a site, particularly a personal / professional site.  Biggest thing I'm seeing on your site is almost nonexistent image compression / optimization. Here are some guidelines:

**Use JPEGs for photographs and gradients. Use PNGs (or GIFs) for line art or text**. This has to do with the compression algorithms used for each type of image.

Usually **a JPEG compression rate of 80%** is pretty good for most images on the web, including all of your thumbnail / gallery shots. For example, this JPEG here: http://www.jj-triggs.com/images/page4_img3.jpg is 25k. 25k!!! That's HUGE, and you've got like 15 of them on the page! At an 80% compression rate (image size of 7k) I can detect a few [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) but I'm also a professional designer & am looking for it. Even at 85%, the image size drops to about 8k.

Ditto your background images. bg_img1.jpg is clocking in at about 900k; bg_img2.jpg is 1.5 mb. This is crazy! Particularly since the cityscape is partially blurred out already — there's no detail to preserve that warrants a total lack of JPEG compression. I knocked the compression on bg_img2.jpg to 60%, got a filesize of <200k, and there's almost no detectable difference in quality: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/1y3V2B2r0S1W0T1i081n/cityscape-compressed.jpg?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=695722fcc5cecec10f09e16181dbdf5f&v=3cf18008.

Sometimes, when the image is the focus of the content / site, it's okay for it to be big and less-compressed. But these images in your background and your galleries are just not important: they're background images. They're not meant to be studied. The gallery images ditto; they're just giving the user an idea of what they'll get on the next click.

**Use selective JPEG compression.** Adobe Fireworks offers this — if you have a large image where part of it is sharp and in focus but the rest is blurry or will be covered by content, you can select a region that you want a higher JPEG compression rate for (say 85%) and crank the rest of the image down to 50% or whatever. For example, here's Cityscape with selective JPEG selection https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/2V1I1o0B1H0v2O141w1R/cityscape-compressed-selective.jpg?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=695722fcc5cecec10f09e16181dbdf5f&v=375e11ed. The in-focus parts are at 75%; the rest is at 50% with smoothing turned on.

**Don't use graphics for text.** In this day of TypeKit, Google Webfonts, and reasonable typographical control via CSS, it's almost never necessary.

**Reduce the number of files that need to be transferred.** Each image, JavaScript file, CSS file, etc. require their own HTTP request in addition to download times.

Here are a few articles about image compression and download times:

- http://www.noupe.com/design/everything-you-need-to-know-about-image-compression.html
- http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/speed-up-your-website-with-better-image-optimization-in-photoshop/
- http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/how-to-minimize-load-time-for-fast-user-experiences/

Answer (score 5):

It a long reply ... but I feel it provides enough details to some basic approaches to improve a site's performance.
The following answer will also be applicable to almost any site.
Any specific examples provided below might be for current version of http://www.jj-triggs.com/

In the points below, I'm referring to the usage of Net Panel of Firebug add-on in Firefox but other browsers
also have similar tools with almost the same approach as I have mentioned.

Install Firebug on Firefox and open your website.
Enable Firebug for your site (F12).
Enable Firebug's Net panel if it is not enabled already.

Your site: http://www.jj-triggs.com/
    - takes 5-6 seconds on my system for repeat visits (For this answer, I have not mentioned approaches to improve on this)
    - but the first visit took around 60 seconds. (The points below focus on how to improve on that)
      Most of the points mentioned below would improve your site for the first load (or fresh reloads)

After having loaded the page already, to test fresh loads, you can use Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+R, Ctrl+Shift+R (depending on the browser).
Monitor the Net Panel of Firebug when the page is loading.

## How much time a site takes depends on:

```
- The speed of the site host server (seems OK, nothing much to do for now)

- Visitor's connection speed (cannot do anything for it)

- Everything else (where you need to fix many things).
  The important approaches to resolve them are listed below:
    - Serve the user files with less size but same content:
        - Approach:
            Enable gzip on files which contain text contents (*.js, *.css, *.html etc) (currently your site does not use gzip)
        - How to identify:
            In Net panel, expand the HTTP request details for a file, in the Headers tab of the expanded details, Content-Encoding field should show the value gzip.
        - Solution:
            It might need you to modify .htaccess file (or some other approach based on the server)
            Search on Google or StackOverflow to see how to enable it.

        - Approach:
            Use minified JS and CSS files
        - How to identify:
            In Net panel, expand the HTTP request details for a JS/CSS file, in the Response tab of the expanded details, the code should be a minified version (no whitespace characters) of the file.
        - Solution:
            Use either the minified JS/CSS files as provided by the library.
            Or you can minify them yourself by using tools like "JSMin" or "YUI (CSS and JS) Compressor"

    - Approach:
        - Serve the user optimum images, i.e., less size with good enough quality
    - How to identify:
        - In Net Panel, go to Images tab > Sort by size
        - Generally the size of the images should be ... 1kb to 30kb for simple icons and logos and 20kb to 250kb for photos and large backgrounds.
    - Solution:
        - Compress the large images with softwares like GIMP (free) or Photoshop.

    - Approach:
        - Load the files from a CDN if possible
        - eg: Load jQuery, jQuery UI etc from popular but still free CDN
        - Advantage even for first visit: If the user has visited any other site which refers to the same path, it would be fetched from the cache itself
    - How to identify:
        - Check the Net panel's "Domain" column for popular libraries like jQuery, jQuery UI etc.
          They should be getting loaded from a popular CDN such as Google.
    - Solution:
        - Include JS and CSS from (Google) CDN if available.

    - Approach:
        - Load CSS before JS
        - It may not necessarily help much with faster loading completion,
          but it usually gives a faster feeling of load because your CSS gets applied as soon as possible.
    - How to identify:
        - Check the Timeline column in Net panel. Usually CSS files should be the getting loaded before JS.
    - Solution:
        - Move the <script> tags towards the bottom of the page.

    - Approach:
        - Wherever possible, load third-party components like Google Maps dynamically after the page load has completed
    - How to identify:
        - Check the Timeline column in Net panel. The 3rd-party components should usually begin loading after almost all the other code for the site has loaded.
    - Solution:
        - The solution would depend on the third-party component and might be a bit tricky.
          Generally, loading the 3rd-party JavaScript after a small delay (using window.setTimeout and code to dynamically add script tags) would provide you better performance compared to loading the 3rd-party JS using plain HTML.
```

I believe fixing these mentioned issues might reduce your (http://www.jj-triggs.com/) first load time to 10-30% of the time it takes currently.

Answer (score 4):

Use `YSlow` [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) for Firefox. It will give you detailed analysis on various performance buckets.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this [site](http://www.gomez.com/Instant-Test) and [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) where you can check daily Performance of your site

Answer (score 3):

You could have a check here too :
[Test site](http://www.monitoring-transactionnel.com/outils-gratuits/ee70a1b51b5ba741a2fc95dba07e7d2d2441073a)

This test shows you images are a great contributors to your load time. In particular background images that seems to be not optimized and weight 1.4 MB

Study this, reduce your number of requests, downscale your images, defer loading and you should begin to reduce your load time

Disclaimer : I am one of the dev invovlved in the free tool above

Answer (score 3):

The main problem on this page are the big images bg_img1.jpg, bg_img2.jpg and bg_img3.jpg. They have a size between 0.91MB and 1.45MB.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is mentioning problems related to network traffic, but page load could also be due to JavaScript. Here are some tricks I've picked up on that subject...

Chrome developer tools has a profiler built right in to the browser. You can start it, by opening up developer tools, clicking profiles, click start and perform whatever task you'd like.

This profiler will tell you where your application time is being spent and what functions are taking up the most of your time.

Since JavaScript is single threaded if you perform lots of stuff on application "init" then your page will be unresponsive for a short period of time. How can you know if there is some JS that is blocking? Well, the main symptom is when you scroll your mouse wheel or click on things nothing happens for some noticeable amount of time on page load.

What happens to your scroll events and clicks during this time? Well they get placed on the event queue. The event queue gets called whenever other JavaScript is not executing. Often the cause of these problems can be traced back by the root by clicking the "Pause" button in a JS debugger and exploring the stack trace... yes, that's how slow execution could be!

Below are some problems/solutions

### Problem: Unresponsive page, on page load

There are generally 2 ways to fix these sorts of problems:
- First (the not so good, but often reasonable way) you could take expensive operations that may run in a for loop on page load and throw them in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)`. Note: 0 is actually 4ms or 5ms and your operation gets thrown onto the event queue. This lets more parts of your application to load before needing to do much heavy lifting.
- Second, architect your app in such a way that these operations only get run when they are needed rather than throwing everything in page 'ready' or 'load'. This is very much a preventative measure or a refactor. It is generally hard to untangle these sorts of problems.

### Problem: Clicking/Interacting is slow (after page load)

You can usually solve this by doing a better job a delegating events. Event bubbling is something everyone should know in JS. In short, think about how a click event on 1 object is actually a click occurring on every parent that contains that object. Delegation is using that fact to allow you to create 1 handler for many DOM elements that do similar/same thing. Read the docs for jQuery's `on` method and really focus in on how to use the `filter` parameter, and what `e.currentTarget` vs `e.target` vs `this` are.

### Problem: Waiting too long for initial AJAX calls

One way to fix this is to make the AJAX request sooner. You could place the request on page load but before the page is ready. Then your request will be parallelized with the rest of your page assets being loaded.

### Problem: Too many JS files

People now a days use module systems (check out AMD and CommonJS), but the most basic way to resolve having too much network traffic that delays page load is to cat all your JS files. Now if you have 100k lines of JS then you are going to have the opposite problem (compiling JS takes too long and you need to split up your files). Generally, bundling everything up is a quick fix solution though. You could also divide your network traffic out onto multiple sub-domains. This will allow you to parallelize more downloads. I believe browsers have a cap at 6 downloads per domain right now. A CDN would also help this.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox/Chrome/IE - press F12, which opens up a developer panel, where you should be able to find a network panel.

Or try: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use Chrome and the Dev Toolbar (Network tab) to watch what are the heavy elements.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an older question, I would like to toss out one more EXCELLENT free tool that can be used for finding performance issues with a website.

Compuware's (dnyaTrace) AJAX Free Edition tool has helped me resolve some things I missed on a couple of my sites in the past...  I recall having a caching issues (htaccess related) that I discovered using the tool, among other great tips.

In any case, it can currently be downloaded here:
http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/ajax-free-edition/overview.html